# Free, Blazing Speed OCR Software for integration with programs

Tags: windows, linux, software-development, ocr, font

I need to do optical character recognition in given places on a certain window in order to make an add-on for that application. The application is a C family game made with HGE compiled to executable. Are there any good OCR solutions for this out there?

It needs to be able to process all text on the screen in seconds or milliseconds.

I'm dealing with a few different fonts, each one is the same size, always. A few different possible colors. Some text has a uniform color or gradient backround, but most doesn't.

The OCR should be run on Windows 10 or the latest Ubuntu.

Are there any OCR programs out there that I can feed font data to?  Image or ttf?

Comment: The idea was that to have a lot better performance it would be better to read/scan/skim the text *before* it is rendered. I.e. Read the html instead of doing ocr on the screen. However I don't know if that can be done for hge programs, unless you have access to the code.

Answer (score 1):

The undeniably best free and open OCR software is [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract). However, the performance is definitely lacking.

In this software field there don't seem to be fast AND free solution, as described by this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17717176/723876).